# Detect if screen is mirrored due to localisation change Android

Tags: android, translation, mirroring

Android is mirroring screen when Arabic localisation is set.
Since Im adding images programaticaly using x,y cords, mirroring screen messed up the basal cord system.
For fix it, I need to detect if the screen is mirrored, or normal. In case the screen is mirrored, I would provide negative X values and that fixes the problem.
So, How to detect mirrored screen due to Arabic translation?

Comment: Check View.layoutDirection

Comment: You saved me. Thanks a lot!